# Java: Is there a way to find the count of files in a directory without having to list all the files?

Tags: java, file, count

I currently use the below code to find the count of files in a directory:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
count = files.length;
```

The main issue with this is that the cpu usage goes way above if the number of files in the directory are huge (100k or above). Is there any memory efficient way to get the count of files?

I don't want to perform any native calls.

Comment: edited my question just now. I do not want to use any native calls.

Comment: Please don't use "lakh", the amount of people understanding it is few here. Use 1k for 1000 or 100k for 1 lakh. 1m etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Or at least not using standard Java tools.

You could keep the information about the directory and the files in some sort of data structure you define in your program, or simply store the count somewhere, but that's only useful if you want to get information about the same directory many times.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it using standard Java.

You may be able to approximate it though by taking the count once and then keeping track of how many times you add and remove things. That only works if you are the only one adding and removing files though.

Slightly more complicated would be to use the java nio functionality to monitor the folder for changes.

Count the folder once, then monitor the folder for changes and as files are added and removed update your count.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve better performance try to change listFiles() method to list() method from File class.

Comment: Had tried it. list is slightly better than listFiles but still it does eat up more cpu.